# "Handle is invalid" when updating in TortoiseHG workbench and using svn subrepository

Tags: svn, mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using mercurial HG with a SVN subrepo.

My problem is when trying to merge or update revisions in my root repository using the TortoiseHG workbench. For some reason I always get the error:

```
"abort: The handle is invalid".
```

It is still possible to commit and update using the explorer plugin (Using rightclick, submit/update).

I have two levels of subrepos. One from my client-code that includes the Engine as a subrepository, and the engine that includes other subrepositories as dependencies.

in my .subrepo i define the path to the repository like this

```
**Root repository .hgsub**
External/Engine = //Mcp/hg/Engine

**Engine repository .hgsub**
Externals/Box2d = [svn]http://box2d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

My folder structure is something like this

```
root
    -> Externals/Engine
                       -> Externals/Box2d
```

Am I doing something wrong? Should I place the svn repo folder ouside the engine-folder? Other ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
**Root repository .hgsub**
External/Engine = //Mcp/hg/Engine

**Engine repository .hgsub**
Externals/Box2d = [svn]http://box2d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

to:

```
**Root repository .hgsub**
External/Engine = file://Mcp/hg/Engine

**Engine repository .hgsub**
Externals/Box2d = [svn]http://box2d.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

So that mercurial knows which type or reference your root repo is.  *I am assuming that it is not on a server in this case.*